# adding data on the flow to eloquent objects

Tags: laravel-5, collections, push, put

I would like to pass some extra data to my laravel Mail class via Eloquent object and I was trying the following which do not works

```
$user->properties()->save($properties);
$user->roles()->sync($request->role_id);
$user->push($tmpPass);
//than I tried put

$user->put('index', $tmpPass);
var_dump($user);
die;

Mail::to($user->email)->send(new UserCreated($user));
```

Is the trying on the wrong track? How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing variable to the mailable, not to the eloquent class, like so:

`Mail::to($user->email)->send(new UserCreated($user, $tmpPass));`

and UserCreated is like:

```
class UserCreated extends Mailable
{
    public $user;
    public $tmpPass;

    public function __construct(User $user, $tmpPass)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->tmpPass = $tmpPass;
    }
    ....
}
```

and you'll have both `$user` and `$tmpPass` available inside your blade template.